# How do I use {{file_url()}} to get image field URLs in views-view-fields.html.twig?

Tags: views, 9

I tried to use the following code in views-view-fields.

```
{{ file_url(fields.field_featured_image.content.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

When I use that code, I get this error.

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGenerator::generateString() must be of the type string, null given, called in /home/vito/Desktop/D9-fabco-v2/fabco-v2/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(418): eval()'d code on line 45 in Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGenerator->generateString() (line 58 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileUrlGenerator.php).

What's the correct way to use `{{ file_url() }}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that in other way:

In created views and in there have the image filed
[image]

Than changed the image formatter
[image]

Than in views-view-fields.html.twig

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url({{fields.field_featured_image.content|striptags|raw}});"></div>
```

be-careful with quotation marks and spaces that can cause why your image not displayed.

If you have better solution please do not hesitate post it here in comments